# Using an EaseUS pbd backup with VMWare Workstation - winload.efi error

Tags: boot, backup, uefi, vmware-workstation, recovery

Hopefully someone can offer some assistance.

I have a Windows 10 `pbd` backup that was create using EaseUS. Pretty sure something is wrong with the boot settings in this backup, but it is what it is.

When recovering the backup to my laptop, to 2nd disk, I managed to add it to the boot table by executing the following command from the main OS

```
bcdboot f:\windows /m {......} /addlast /d
```

However, when trying to do the exact same thing, in the same order, in my VMWare Workstation 17 Pro I end up getting the following error when trying to boot to the `pbd` restored OS

```
Recovery
Your PC/Device needs to be repaired.
The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.
File: \windows\system32\winload.efi
Error Code: 0xc000000c
```

I tried everything Google has to offer on the subject, nothing works. I made sure my VM is in `uefi` format, I tried using a Win installation media to fix it - nothing works.

Would appreciate some new ideas.

Answer (score 0):

VMware Workstation (I use it all the time) will not open the backup directly.

You must convert it to a VMDK file.

Easus provides a facility to do this.

[Open Easus backup file](https://www.easeus.com/todo-backup-guide/convert-physical-to-virtual.html)

1. Launch EaseUS Todo Backup and click "Tools"  -> "P2V Recovery".
2. Then select the disk and partition backup image file to convert.
3. Choose the virtual machine name and then select the virtual software vendor: VMware or Virtual PC. Click Browse to modify the location to save the image file.
4. Click "Proceed".

If the above does not work, then your backup or original file is damaged or corrupted.

You will likely need some local recovery assistance.

Comment: I did EXACTLY that - sadly it provided a virtual disk and not an actual machine. I then created a new machine and tried to use the virtual disk file - and ended up exactly where I was before. If I don't have another OS in the machine the OS won't load at all and will just get stuck on the VMWare screen that lets you choose what to boot, if I install a 2nd OS and try to add the virtual disk as a 2nd boot option - I end up with the same error.

Comment: This means the backup or original file is damaged or corrupted.   

I added that to my answer. You probably need some local recovery assistance at this point.

Comment: But then how do you explain the fact it worked just fine on my actual physical laptop with zero issues?

Comment: Managed to fix it using this https://woshub.com/how-to-repair-deleted-efi-partition-in-windows-7/

Comment: I suspect the conversion tool need the image to work properly and that is what you did with the other tool

Answer (score 0):

Like I originally said, the image had its boot manager corrupted, no idea why it worked fine with a physical laptop and not in the VM. Anyways, I managed to fix it using this:

https://woshub.com/how-to-repair-deleted-efi-partition-in-windows-7/

Comment: To improve your answer, you should explain the main points from the link.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).